# Multi-target netstandard1.0 and netstandard2.0 side-by-side?

Tags: csproj, multitargeting, dotnet-sdk

When I create a multi-target .NET csproj which targets netstandard1.2, netstandard2.0 and net45, do I have to include both of the netstandard monikers in the  section of the .csproj or is it enough to just mention netstandard1.2 (the lower netstandard version)?

**Proposal A:**

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;net45</TargetFrameworks>`

**Proposal B:**

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference between the behavior of netstandard1.x and netstandard2.x.

From [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting):

> ✔️ **DO include a `netstandard2.0` target if you require a `netstandard1.x` target.**
>
> All platforms supporting .NET Standard 2.0 will use the `netstandard2.0` target and benefit from having a smaller package graph while older platforms will still work and fall back to using the `netstandard1.x` target.

And one paragraph above explains the difference:

> .NET Standard 1.x is distributed as a granular set of NuGet packages, which creates a large package dependency graph and results in developers downloading a lot of packages when building. Modern .NET platforms, including .NET Framework 4.6.1, UWP and Xamarin, all support .NET Standard 2.0. You should only target .NET Standard 1.x if you specifically need to target an older platform.

`netstandard1.x` supports 2 frameworks by using nugets, which causes the import of many packages.

Comment: Okay, you mean, if there are no preprocessor directives for 1.2- resp. 2.0-specific implementations, I can just specify netstandard1.2? That's what I thought. Someone asked me in this github issue (https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper/issues/31) that it is better to target netstandard2.0 too "in order to have a smaller dependency graph"... I don't understand this statement.

Comment: Using a NuGet package (ObjectDumper.NET) which defines ```<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;net45</TargetFrameworks>```

- Project 1: TargetFramework: netstandard1.2
```<PackageReference Include="ObjectDumper.NET" Version="2.2.19011.1" />```

- Project 2: TargetFramework netstandard2.0
```<PackageReference Include="ObjectDumper.NET" Version="2.2.19011.1" />```

Now, if I install version 2.2.19015.4-pre of ObjectDumper.NET which defines ```<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>```
I cannot see any difference. There is no additional NuGet package install

Answer (score 0):

When I check the dependencies of both NuGet packages **(1)** with `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;net45</TargetFrameworks>` and **(2)** with `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>` I see that netstandard1.2 includes **NETStandard.Library (>=1.6.1)** which is probably the "depedency graph" which is described in @Baruch's answer.

ObjectDumper.Net dependencies **(1)**

[image: ObjectDumper.NET with netstandard1.2 only]

ObjectDumper.Net dependencies **(2)**

[image: ObjectDumper.NET with netstandard1.2 and netstandard2.0]

To my knowledge, I can use `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2;net45</TargetFrameworks>` if I want to support both, netstandard1.2 and netstandard2.0. A netstandard2.0 project which consumes a netstandard1.2 NuGet package references NETStandard.Library 2.0.3 (which fulfills the minimum requirement >=1.6.1). So, no unnecessary NuGet packages will be installed.